# Не понятен запрос Graphql

Tags: graphql

Есть код, рабочий но в const LAUNCH_QUERY странная строка
$flight_number: Int!
1.Если уберу знак "$"  то запрос ломается если поставлю `${}`(обычная строка в es6) запрос также поломается понимаю что это переменная и в ней айдишник содержится, но как получается что переменная записана в таком виде $flight_number???
2. что за Int!  понятно что сравнение по числу но почему в таком виде???
Вот весь код если надо

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const LAUNCH_QUERY = gql`
query LaunchQuery($flight_number: Int!){
    launch(flight_number: $flight_number){
        flight_number,
        mission_name,
        launch_year,
        launch_success,
        launch_date_local,
        rocket{
            rocket_id,
            rocket_name,
            rocket_type
        }
    }
}`
;

export class Launch extends Component {
  render() {
      let {flight_number} = this.props.match.params;
      flight_number = parseInt(flight_number);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Query query={LAUNCH_QUERY} variables={{flight_number}}>
        {
            ({loading, error, data}) => {
                if(loading) return <h4>Loading...</h4>
                if(error) console.log(error);
                console.log(data);
                const {mission_name, flight_number, launch_year, launch_success,
                     rocket: {rocket_id, rocket_name, rocket_type}} = data.launch;
                return <div>
                    <h1 className="display-4 my-3">
                    <span className="text-dark">Mission: {mission_name}</span>
                    </h1>
                    <h4 className="mb-3">Launch Details</h4>
                    <ul className="list-group">
                    <li className="list-group-item">
                    Flight Number: {flight_number}
                    </li>
                    <li className="list-group-item">
                    Launch Year: {launch_year}
                    </li>
                    <li className="list-group-item">
                    Launch Successful <span className={launch_success ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger'}>{launch_success ? 'Yes' : 'No'}</span>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                    <h4 className="my-3">Rocket Details</h4>
                    <ul className="list-group">
                        <li className="list-group-item">Rocket ID: {rocket_id}</li>
                        <li className="list-group-item">Rocket Name: {rocket_name}</li>
                        <li className="list-group-item">Rocket Type: {rocket_type}</li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr/>
                    <Link to="/" className="btn btn-secondary">Back</Link>
                </div>
            }
        }
        </Query>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default Launch
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не правильно поняли. `$flight_number: Int!` это захват переменной из контекста.
Строка:

```
query LaunchQuery($flight_number: Int!){
```

захватавает переменную и передаёт в

```
launch(flight_number: $flight_number)
```

**Int!** - это не сравнение, а тип захватываемой переменной. В данном случае **Integer**. А восклицательный знак на конце типа указывает что переменная обязательна(не может быть null).

более подробно можете прочитать в документации [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables)